# Paragraphs wrapping other paragraphs of different font sizes

Tags: html, css

This is difficult to explain

I have a div tag that includes many p tags. These p tags are varying font sizes up to 250.

I would like the text to wrap the larger font sizes. For instance, if I have a paragraph with the work "ok" with a font size of 250, I want the other paragraph tags to wrap around it instead of having one line like it is now.
This must remain a single div tag containing multiple p tags.
Here are images explaining what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVvqx.jpg

I should add, the order of the other paragraphs do not matter, they can be completely random just as long as there are multiple lines wrapping the larger fonts, so the last paragraph can be at the top. Whichever can fit the most text in the smallest area is what I am looking for.

I have put an example on jsfiddle, `asdf, qwer, sd, and ds` should be stacked on top of each other beside `test`
http://jsfiddle.net/rfcy2f15/1/

Comment: Why can't more div tags be used within the div? This makes styling it the way you want a lot easier. Can we use p tags and style those like divs?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about my english and I'n not sure that I understand you but this could help you: http://jsfiddle.net/4kLyxgpx/

```
p {
    display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div>
    <p style='font-size: 100px;display: inline; float:left;'>test</p>
    <p style='font-size: 20px;'>asdf</p>
    <p style='font-size: 12px;'>qwer</p>
    <p style='font-size: 10px;'>sd</p>
    <p style='font-size: 10px;'>ds</p>
    <p style='font-size: 40px;'>csd</p>
    <p style='font-size: 10px;'>werw</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, however, the p tags are added dynamically so they need to be identical

Comment: Is it possible to simply cram the text into a box wherever it best fits?

Comment: Ok, if p are added dynamically you could do that: `p {display:block; line-height: 100%; margin:0} p:first-child { display: inline; float:left; }`

Comment: The first paragraph is not always the largest and should therefore not be the one floating every time. Some times the largest font is in the middle.

Comment: But you need something that make your "special" p different